# Laravel password broker facade

Tags: php, laravel, passwords

How can I match user with token using a password broker facade in Laravel 5.5?

I am sending a mail to user by generating a token:

```
app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($this->user)
```

This automatically fills the `password_resets` table in DB with user email and with token value which looks like it is hashed.

The callback URL for user is `password-reset/{token}` and now I want to check whether token is valid by checking if it exists in the DB and if user connected to it even triggered a password reset.

```
$tokenValid = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $input['token'])->first();
```

This however does not work as the token from the input is not hashed in any way. I tried this also

```
$tokenValid = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', bcrypt($input['token']))->first();
```

But the hashed value comes out incorrectly.

Does someone know how to match it with DB value?

Comment: Can you please explain what is "broker"?  I mean what is your naming convention says, on naming thing brokers. Thank you.

Comment: That is the facade's name, I didn't name it myself :)

Comment: Thank you, I filed a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489562/laravel-5-naming-conventions-broker-vs-manager) about the brokers in naming convention. It seems no one knows the answer.

Comment: I don't know either. TBH, I do not follow SO strictly naming conventions, but rather what makes sense for me. I understand your concern if it is a huge project though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Two hashes, even though different, may match. Doing a `bcrypt()` function twice on the same string will not produce the same hash, so there is a helper method to check if the hashes match:

```
Hash::check($input['token'], $token->token)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the unhashed token into (password_resets) database table like this:-

```
public function forgotpassword_post(){
    $admin=Admin::where('email',request('email'))->first();
    if(!empty($admin)){
        $token=app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($admin);
        Mail::to($admin->email)->send(new AdminResetPassword(['data'=>$admin,'token'=>$token]));
        DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
            'email'=>$admin->email,
            'token'=>$token,
            'created_at'=>Carbon::now()
        ]);
        Session::flash('success','sent');
        return back();
    }
 return back();
```

}

you can check for token validation like this  :-

```
public function reset_password($token){

 $check_token= DB::table('password_resets')->where('token',$token)->where('created_at','>',Carbon::now()->subHours(2))->first();
 if(!empty($check_token)){
  return view('admin.reset_password',['data'=>$check_token]);
 }else{
     return redirect('/admin/forgorpassword');
 }
```

}