# Laravel 5 Naming Conventions - Broker VS Manager

Tags: php, laravel, naming-conventions

`Broker` - is a word that sometimes comes into the naming convention, at least we have a `PasswordBroker`.

But more often they are `Managers` like in - `Support\Manager` and `Queue\Capsule\Manager`...

What is the difference? When it should be Broker?

PS

I know that Laravel people for some reson don't like the word `interface` and say `Contract` instead. Is it the same here?

Comment: Broker is typically an entity which acts as a middle man for an exchange. Manager is more for asset / logistic handling. My two cents.